# How to add and run migration from plugin root folder?

Tags: plugin-development, migration

I'm trying to add a new table to an existing plugin.
I can't add it to the `Install` migration as I want existing installations to pull the change.

The problems I ran into:

1. I can't run Craft CLI (`php craft migrate/create`) from the **plugin** folder (as opposed to the project folder)
2. If I add a migration manually to the `migrations` folder of the **plugin** I can't get the root project to identify and run it.

What is the best practice for this kind of change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't run Craft CLI (php craft migrate/create) from the plugin folder (as opposed to the project folder)

From the project folder run:

```
php craft migrate/create my_migration_name --plugin=my-plugin-handle
```

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/migrations.html#creating-migrations

> If I add a migration manually to the migrations folder of the plugin I can't get the root project to identify and run it.

I have managed to run it manually:

```
php craft migrate --plugin=my-plugin-handle
```

For Craft to run the new migration on update you need to increase the `schemaVersion` of the plugin under the `Plugin` Class (Defaults to 1.0.0). e.g:

```
public string $schemaVersion = '1.0.1';
```

However, it seems that migration needs to be added to `Install` migration as well for fresh installations, which would require code duplication or extracting the migration into a service class or trait. Though I can't see this pattern followed in Craft Commerce for example (https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/tree/develop/src/migrations).